# Join two tables on two entities that won't be used in the results

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to join two tables A and B. I don't need to use the article number but that is my joining keys between the two. I need the department that the article falls under in table B. But when I join them and pull only the category then there are duplicates.

I've tried summing up the sales thinking and the units but that just blows the number up and doesn't seem right.

```
SELECT a.[Week End Date]
      ,a.[Cal Year #]
      ,a.[Week #]
      ,b.Department
      ,a.[Site #]
      ,a.[$ Sales ]
      ,a.[Qty Sales ]
  FROM database.cbg.tableA a
  left join database.cbg.tableB b on a.[Article #]=b.[Article #]
  where a.[Cal Year #] = '2018'
  order by a.[Week End Date]
```

I expect the result to be the sales and qty broken down by the department for each site for each week.

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server. Considering that you are using 3 part table, it *appears* you're using SQL Server here, not MySQL.

Comment: If you are getting duplicates, then it's because you have a many to one/many relationship on `a.[Article #]=b.[Article #]` If there shouldn't be a many relationship, something is wrong with your data and you need to find out where the duplicate rows are.

Comment: Please show some sample data, actual results and expected results.

Comment: what you are searching is a group by see https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/sql/t-sql/queries/select-group-by-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15